# An Example for Not Sufficient Linkage

Tags: c++, linkage

According to the [Linkage Section of this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration),

> If a variable, function, or another entity with the same name is declared in several scopes, but does not have sufficient linkage, then several instances of the entity are generated.

Any simple example for the **does not have sufficient linkage** case?

Comment: The levels of linkage come immediately after the paragraph you quoted. For example, "no linkage" is the lowest level of linkage and is insufficient for any use outside the block.

Comment: @RaymondChen Can you elaborate? 1. The link does not specify which one of no/internal/external/module linkage are sufficient. And 2. I am looking for source code and compilation procedure that results in A) an executable program, and B) several instances of an entity being generated.

Comment: Formal wording is invariably hard to penetrate, typical language specification problem.  Concrete examples are local variable declarations, they have no linkage so you can re-use the identifier names as often as you like.  A function that is declared static has internal linkage, you can re-use the identifier in any source file.  If you get it wrong then you'd usually get a linker error.

Comment: 1. "Sufficient linkage" is relative to the points of reference. For example, a name referenced twice within the same translation unit has sufficient linkage if it is internal or external, and even "no linkage" is sufficient if the two references are from the same scope. 2. `void f() { static int a; } void g() { static int a; } void h() { static int a; }` There are three instances of `a`.